# Excel – как добавлять пустые ячейки?

Tags: excel

Есть шаблон страницы в экселе, куда добавляются данные.
В первом столбце данные идет с инкрементом, но между инкрементами могут быть «дубли», то есть

```
1
2
2
2
3
3
4
5
```

и т.д.

Как сделать так, чтобы автоматически добавлялась пустая строка перед каждым началом инкремента, то есть сделать вот такой вид

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Было бы полезно указать какими средствами вы пытаетесь решить данную задачу. Какой язык используете, какую библиотеку, возможно даже какой-то код у вас есть

Comment: В данном случае нужно решение средствами Excel, так как результат формируется на без шаблона средствами C# - ClosedXML.Report, но это не имеет значения, так как нужно сделать так, чтобы все делал только эксель.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот макрос, который выполняет задачу:

```
Sub addRows()

Dim i As Long, l As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = 0

l = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = l To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i + 1, 1) > Cells(i, 1) Then
    Cells(i + 1, 1).Rows.Resize(1).Insert
    End If
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = 1

End Sub
```

Воспользовался примером отсюда:

https://www.excel-vba.ru/forum/index.php?topic=1664.0

Comment: Вместо строки `Cells(i + 1, 1).Rows.Resize(1).Insert`  достаточно `Rows(i + 1).Insert`